# Jquery Json Parse error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-mobile

This time I am locked by the Json Parse error. Currently I am Developing Web application in Asp.net MVC 4 with jQuery Mobile.In pages **where I have text box and button**, this issue occurs

I am using **jquery 2.1.1 js file** .. Error Occuring in

```
jQuery.parseJSON = function( data ) {
    return JSON.parse( data + "" ); // Here data comes as undefined 
};
```

**Code in the View**
  The below has textbox and buttons in my page

```
 <div class="HwySearchTextBoxSmaller">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.txtPickingScan, new { @autofocus = "autofocus" })
                        </div>

                        <div id="btn" style="float: left; margin-top: 1.2em; margin-left: 1em;">
                            <input type="submit" id="btnSearchMP" name="btnSearchMP" class="Hwy905SearchIcon" data-role="none" value="" />
                        </div>
<div id="dButton">

                    <input type="submit" id="btnMPSearch" name="btnMPSearch"  data-theme="d" value="@Resources.ViewBatch"  />
                    <input type="submit" id="btnMPSearch1" name="btnMPSearch"  data-theme="d" value="@Resources.ViewGrp"  />
            </div>
```

**Whenever I enter into text box , on blurring, on button clicking, on keyup and for other related events this error is popping up**

The error picture I have uploaded.[image: Json Parse Error]

page is not working in any browser because of this issue.

Please Please help me . Definitely I need to find a solution for this. Please help me

**Instead of using jquery 2.1.1 file I used the Google api , for jquery libray which also showed the samer error**

**Below is the dom image of the code**
[image]

Comment: jQuery 2+ removed a lot of support for IE and its backwards ways. Try using 1.11

Comment: this occurring not only in IE but all other browsers

Comment: In that case, please add your code to the question.

Comment: Make sure that you really have a valid JSON string to parse, not just an object that is convert implicitly with toString(). It is possible to show the content of data here?

Comment: Please find my updated question above

Comment: Hi @Daniel I don't have any string to parse with Json, but still I am getting this error

Comment: I have button click event, is that click event giving me any problem ??

Comment: Please show the context where the $.parseJSON function get called.

Comment: jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
 "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
 "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {


This is the code which brings error. The Context is that when a button is clicked after page load , error occurs

Comment: Hi one doubt, I have accidentally removed a folder named packages in MVC project currently I am developing, is because  of this issue occurring to me ??

Answer (score 0):

Try to improve your function in a kind like that:

```
jQuery.parseJSON = function (data) {
   console.log(data + "");
   return JSON.parse(data + "");
};
```

Ensure that the caller of the $.parseJSON function supplies a correct formatted parameter "data". You can use the debugger of the browser to inspect the caller stack.

Comment: Ya Daniel , the thing is that I know data is not valid , but what workaround or solution can i try to get rid of this

Comment: The exact situation is that, when i have script for button or textbox, an when we click that button or text box this issue happens

Comment: Use an online JSON validator to validate your JSON. Edit it there and hardcode the corrected JSON to feed your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is related to `JSON` data. There could be issues with the *syntax* of the JSON that you are using. I would suggest that you *validate* the JSON online using some online `JSON Validator` tools like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com. Once you have corrected the JSON, use the same JSON by hardcoding it in your code to test this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Got the solution for the above problem. Actually while bundling the js files I removed validate and validate unobtrusive js files and the problem got solved . Thank you to all for helping me