# file with jquery.validate.unobtrusive in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

We using following files for bundling in mvc4.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"));
```

We got parse **Jquery Json Parse error** please see below link.

[Click Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625721/jquery-json-parse-error)

After struggling lot we found the bug due to jquery.validate.unobtrusive file so we uploaded to latest version that suite mvc 4 from below link.

[jquery.validate file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js)

Now we thought all will works fine 90% we succeed no **Jquery Json Parse error** but the button in mvc is not working after postback. what will be wrong? Please guide me.

Comment: show the button code as well then

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee : its occuring in whole application bro. so posting code is tough one. i think jquery.validate is not compatible with jquery.validate.unobtrusive. plzguide me which version of jquery.validate  i should use

Comment: it should be validate and unabstrucsive works well together

Comment: you should be using both with same version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast i found the issue guys. the problem is i rendered validate.js and validate.unobtrusive.js with same jquery bundling. so validation applied for all pages. when i removed both file from bundling all works fine.